# How to reset motes (Telosb) at same time?

Tags: hardware

I need to start the motes to let them run at the same time, then monitor their behavior by their serial output, the only observer is my PC.

Except to restart the mote by pressing the reset button on the board, is there any other ways to reset them all at same time? Like how it works in COOJA (simulator) or testbed.(E.g., flocklab).

For example, is it possible to reset them by sending a command to their serial port at same time?

Comment: Well, there should be a command manual in which you could check if there is a reset command, should not be?